# Better ajax toggle performance for checkbox attr with select change

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im creating a simple message system with a mail inbox like UI. I have a select box that witll control a list of check box one for each message. It works fine but i need it with less code lines.

heres my code:

```
jQuery("#select_deselect").change(function(){
  switch (jQuery(this).val()){
   case 'unread':
    jQuery("input[class=new_message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    });
    jQuery("input[class=message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
   break;
   case 'read':
    jQuery("input[class=message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    });
    jQuery("input[class=new_message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
   break;
   case 'all':
    jQuery("input[class=new_message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    });
    jQuery("input[class=message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    });
   break;
   case 'none':
     jQuery("input[class=new_message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
    jQuery("input[class=message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
   break;
   default:
    jQuery("input[class=new_message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
    jQuery("input[class=message]").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
   }
 });
```

select_deselect is the id of my select box with options (null, all, read, unread, none).

new_message is the class asignesd to unread messages

message is the class asigned to read messages

i think a toggle() can doit but it will be the same lines.

Any idea to get this simply as posible

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop each of the elements after you select them you can just call your .attr() or .removeAttr() on it.

```
jQuery("#select_deselect").change(function(){
    var newmessage = jQuery("input[class=new_message]");
    var message = jQuery("input[class=message]");
    switch (jQuery(this).val()){
        case 'unread':
            newmessage.attr("checked", "checked");
            message.removeAttr("checked");
        break;
        case 'read':
            message.attr("checked", "checked");
            newmessage.removeAttr("checked");
        break;
        case 'all':
            newmessage.attr("checked", "checked");
            message.attr("checked", "checked");
        break;
        case 'none':
        default:
            newmessage.removeAttr("checked");
            message.removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Only caches them per change event but will help if you do anything more then just change the checked value in this function

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#select_deselect").change(function(){
  switch (jQuery(this).val()){
   case 'unread':
    jQuery("input[class=new_message]").attr("checked", "checked");
    jQuery("input[class=message]").removeAttr("checked");
   break;
   case 'read':
    jQuery("input[class=message]").attr("checked", "checked");
    jQuery("input[class=new_message]").removeAttr("checked");
   break;
   case 'all':
    jQuery("input[class=message],input[class=new_message]").attr("checked", "checked");
   break;
   case 'none':
   default:
     jQuery("input[class=message],input[class=new_message]").removeAttr("checked");
   break;
   }
 });
```

I simplified the above by removing the redundant each, and combining the selectors for all and none.

Comment: As a small optimization, i'd use a local var to store all the input to improve speed on each cases.

Comment: correct bgy.. kyle.. its a little bit slower with your optimization but thanks ill keep it for other events.